# mod_proxy_html and Apache 2.2.29: parse all <meta http-equiv="" content=""> and turn them in real http headers

Tags: apache, http, header, mod-proxy-html, http-equiv

I'm using Mamp 3 (pro) on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10; I'v already compiled and installed mod_proxy_html (3.1.2) and mod_xml2enc, they are both correctly loaded by Apache 2.2.29 without issues.

This is my typical html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Authorization" content="Bearer dummyToken">
    <title>Header Test</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

I need to **convert all the `<meta http-equiv="some" content="thing">` to real http headers**. I've already known how to do this via ajax, it's not a problem. But I need to add an oauth token, inside the **Authorization header field**, to get access to various protected resources, like images or video streams, that are not served through ajax but referenced, through an url, directly inside the html.

So, directly inside my httpd.conf I have:

```
ProxyHTMLEnable On
ProxyHTMLMeta On
```

this config *should globally apply to apache*. At the moment my server replies with all the field contained inside the request: it seems that the **ProxyHTMLMeta On is ignored** and all the meta tags are not translated into http headers:

```
Accept: "*/*"
Accept-Encoding: "identity;q=1, *;q=0"
Accept-Language: "it,en;q=0.8"
Connection: "keep-alive"
Cookie: "laravel_session=dummy
DNT: "1"
Host: "192.168.2.2:8888"
Range: "bytes=0-"
User-Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2535.0 Safari/537.36"
```

See, no **Authorization** header. If I call the api from SoapUI:

```
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate",
"Authorization": "Bearer dummy",
"Host": "fillusso:8888",
"Connection": "Keep-Alive",
"User-Agent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)"
```

It's a kind of magic, the header is there (because it directly sent from SoapUI, no parsing or meta tag here).

How can I solve the problem? Am I doing everything all right?

Comment: Wow a real question, been a long time.